# How to stop event bubbling in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using some `JQ` stuff on `check box`, even if the parent `div` is clicked. I am toggling the value of `check box`. Clicking on div is working perfectly but when you click on checkbox the function is called twice. Is there any way to solve this problem? following is my code([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vKNYy/1/))
HTML:

```
<div class="check-unit">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
    <p class="brandList">Model</p>
</div>
```

JQ:

```
$('.check').on('change',function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        console.log("checked");
    }else{
        console.log("unchecked");
    }
});

$('.check-unit').on('click',function(e){
    var checkbox = $(this).children('.check'),
    chhhk= checkbox.attr('checked') ? false : true;
    checkbox.attr('checked',chhhk);
    $(this).children('.check').change();
});
```

I've seen `eventbubbling` problem on `stackoverflow`, but still confused how to do this. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vKNYy/1/)

Comment: You can do it in multiple ways, `event.stopPropagation()` or `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` or simply `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: **Note:** Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr` for boolean attribute values

Comment: @Praveen `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` are quite different and not interchangable

Answer (score 1):

Only execute the callback on the parent element if the target is not the input

```
$('.check').on('change',function(e){
    if(this.checked){
        console.log("checked");
    }else{
        console.log("unchecked");
    }
});

$('.check-unit').on('click',function(e){
    if ( ! $(e.target).hasClass('check')) {
        $(this).children('.check').prop('checked', function(_,state) {
            return !state;
        }).trigger('change');
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GX8V8/2/)

As a sidenote, this is what `label` elements are for!

Comment: +1 nice, but any reason for why `event.stopPropagation()` didn't worked in this case?

Comment: but when the `p` is clicked `this` will not be same as `e.target` so will it work then

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Nope, but that's not what the OP asked for? I realize the `p` was probably part of the issue, but the question was asking specifically about clicking the `div`, so I wrote something for that, being a little nitpicky. Changed it to work with the `p` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .prop() instead of .attr() to set the checked property.

```
$('.check').on('change', function (e) {
    if (this.checked) {
        console.log("checked");
    } else {
        console.log("unchecked");
    }
}).click(function (e) {
    //prevent clicks in the checksboxes from bubbling up otherwise when you click on the checkbox the state will get toggled again the event will be bubbled to check-unit which will again toggle the state negating the click
    e.stopPropagation()
});
$('.check-unit').on('click', function () {
    var checkbox = $(this).children('.check'),
        //use .is() and checked-selector to check whether the checkbox is checked
        chhhk = checkbox.is(':checked');
    //use .prop() instead of .attr() & toggle the checked state
    checkbox.prop('checked', !chhhk).change();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZwUpH/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you are clicking the checkbox before changing.

```
$('.check-unit').on('click', function (e) {
    if (!($(e.target).hasClass('check'))) {
        var checkbox = $(this).children('.check'),
            chhhk = checkbox.prop('checked');
        checkbox.prop('checked', !chhhk).change();
    }
});
```

Also note that the code is using prop instead of attr because when you are using boolean attribute values you should use `.prop()`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vKNYy/3/)